# Player gets stuck after 50 sec video playback in Blackberry Simulator

Tags: video, blackberry, mmapi, rim-4.6

I am using blackberry jde 4.6 to test my application in the blackberry 9000 simulator. Some times before I run one `.3gp` video file in my application.

My application consists of one player and two buttons with the name start and stop. If I click the start button then the player will run the `.3gp` file which is stored on the SDCard.

Actually the video file can run one minute and fifty seconds, but if we simply keep the simulator in an idle state while running that video in simulator, after about 50sec the player will get stuck and only after I click any button on the keyboard it continues to run the remaining part of the video file.

If I didn't keep the simulator idle than the file can run continuously.

Comment: I just feel the need to point out that you are debugging problems that are occurring on the simulator.  This could easily be a problem with the simulator that does not exists on your target device.  I would avoid making any changes to your implementation without first running the software on the actual platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't reproduce... But that may be:

- backlight (see [Options->Screen/Keyboard->Backlight timeout](http://www.technipages.com/blackberry-bold-set-backlight-timeout-interval.html))
- performance issue (check in task monitor or performance logs)
- simultaneous access to video file

Comment: Hi thanks for ur response.Can u pls tell me where i can see "Options-->Screen/Keyboard-->Backlight Timeout" either in simulator or JDE .